# Reading file only after function is done

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, fs

I have a function doSmth that creates a file "data.json" by the end. (the file IS created by the end of running the script.) However, when I try to fs.readFileSync it using await and then, it says

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'data.json'
```

here is my code

```
const doSmth = async() => {
    await zip.forEach(async(relativePath: any, file: any) => {
        const fs = require("fs");
        let fileExists = fs.existsSync('data.json');
        if (fileExists) {
            fs.readFileSync('data.json')
            console.log("file already exists")
            fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(""))
        } else {
            console.log("file didnt exist")
            fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(""))
        }
    })
}

await doSmth().then(async () => {
    const fs = require("fs");
    console.log("reached")
    fs.readFileSync("data.json")
})
```

how do I wait for the data.json file to be created before reading it

Edit:
from the comments changed my code to this and works

```
const doSmth = async() => {
    await Promise.all(zip.forEach(async(relativePath: any, file: any) => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const fs = require("fs");
            let fileExists = fs.existsSync('data.json');
            if (fileExists) {
               fs.readFileSync('data.json')
                console.log("file already exists")
               fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(""))
               resolve()
            } else {
               console.log("file didnt exist")
               fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(""))
               resolve()
            }
      })
    }))
}
```

but now I have an await inside and it causes the same data.file not found error

```
const doSmth = async() => {
    await Promise.all(zip.forEach(async(relativePath: any, file: any) => {
        return new Promise(async resolve => {
            const eachFile = await zip.file(file.name).async("string")
            const jsonObject = JSON.parse(eachFile)
            const fs = require("fs");
            let fileExists = fs.existsSync('data.json');
            if (fileExists) {
               fs.readFileSync('data.json')
                console.log("file already exists")
               fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(""))
               resolve()
            } else {
               console.log("file didnt exist")
               fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(""))
               resolve()
            }
      })
    }))
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code of `doSmth`?

Comment: You're using `await` with `then`, and they shouldn't really be used together, but _also_ using async on a function that doesn't need it.

Comment: just editted to show my doSmth. what do i change my code to?

Comment: `forEach` does not work with async code: you should probably use a for loop + await. Your problem is `doSmth` resolving immediately with the use of `forEach`

Comment: how do i change for each to something that works? Im relatively new to async

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are not writing the file synchronously in your catch block

```js
const doSmth = async() => {
    await zip.forEach(async(relativePath: any, file: any) => {
        const fs = require("fs");
        try {
            fs.readFileSync('data.json')
            console.log("file already exists")
            fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(""))
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("file didnt exist")
            fs.writeFileSync('data.json', JSON.stringify(""));
            // Yes, writeFileSync does create a new file when the file is not exists
            // So even this catch is redundant, use fs.existsSync if you really need to know the file exists or not
        }
    })
}
```

or you might want to do a proper primisify for every thing

Comment: thanks changed to fs.existsSync and writeFileSync, however after doSmth I still cannot readFileSync it says error no such file

Comment: @timmy123 read the next answer, that justify the next problem, i mean the latest answer

Comment: thanks i used both suggestions i editted my code above. I have an await inside my promise now thats still causing the delay. any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You are using await, but you are not returning promises.

We will use `Promise.all` to wait for all promises, and for each zip file, we return a `new Promise` when it's done by calling `resolve()`

```
const doSmth = async() => {
    await Promise.all(zip.map(async(relativePath: any, file: any) => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const fs = require("fs");
            let fileExists = fs.existsSync('data.json');
            if (fileExists) {
               fs.readFileSync('data.json')
                console.log("file already exists")
               fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(""))
               resolve()
        } else {
            console.log("file didnt exist")
            fs.writeFileSync("data.json", JSON.stringify(""))
            resolve()
        }
      })
    }))
}
```

PS: I did not count the close brackets, please edit it accordingly.

PS2: your data.json should be empty since you are using `JSON.stringify("")` which is a empty string

#### if you want to do things sequentially

```
import fs from 'fs';
const fsPromises = fs.promises;

const doSmth = async () => {
     return new Promise(async resolve => {
           for (let i = 0; i < zip.length; i++) { 
               const file = zip[i];
               if (await fsPromises.exists(file)) {  
                  await fsPromises.writeFile('data.json', file);
               } 
           }
           resolve(); //End the function by returning a promise.

     })


}
```

Comment: my zip is a json so I cant for loop it

Comment: is zip a file or is it a object? Can you show sample of your object.

Comment: {
  files: [Object: null prototype] {
      'smth': smth
      'smth': smth
    }
  }

Comment: i did try your first code fix with for each and works. But i have an await inside the promise. How do I fix that? I added the code to my question above

Answer (score -1):

Don't mix and match `async/await` with `then`. It looks like you want to do somthing like this.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

async function main() {
  await doSmth();
  console.log('reached');
  fs.readFileSync('data.json');
}

main();
```

Comment: i just editted to show my doSmth. I did try your fix but the script ends before the file is created still. How do I fix the foreach? I am relatively new to async

Comment: Why is `doSmth` async? And why is your `forEach` async? Why are you using synchronous node function functions when you could be using asynchronous ones?

Comment: so what do I change to?